# Identification strategy

Tags: regression, identification

I am trying to find the relationship between one independent variable with two dependent ones. I was doing some reading, and I can use MANOVA to regress this.

However, my original ID strategy was to use RDD because of a natural experiment I'm trying to observe. Hence, I assume I cannot combine these two.

I am trying to observe if there was a change of migration on education quality and quality of life when this reform took place.

Would it be better if I use two separate RDD regressions, or would that cause an issue?

If there exists some other strategy, I would appreciate every suggestion.

Comment: I think it is common in the literature to use separate RDD regressions analyse the effect of a `treatment' on various different outcomes. So I guess using two separate RDD regressions would not be a problem.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thank you for your suggestion!